# Docker commit is not working on windows Server 2019

Tags: docker

I have Windows Server 2019 VM to work with Docker, having 250Gb of HDD and 16 GB ram.

I have written a dockerfile for copying some setups and then manually runs the installation on Containers. Now I need to create the image using those containers. When I use Docker commit it gives issue as

```
"Error response from daemon: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: time=“2019-04-02T12:22:17+05:30” level=error msg=“hcsshim::ImportLayer failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3) path=\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\5bb9eea39e188d382fb8f336112584f3100797ac9fa887012e70c78fa7f2245a folder=C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\hcs981676719”
hcsshim::ImportLayer failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3) path=?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\5bb9eea39e188d382fb8f336112584f3100797ac9fa887012e70c78fa7f2245a folder=C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\hcs981676719"
```

Docker Version:
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version: 18.09.2
API version: 1.39
Go version: go1.10.8
Git commit: 6247962
Built: Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
OS/Arch: windows/amd64
Experimental: false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
Version: 18.09.2
API version: 1.39 (minimum version 1.24)
Go version: go1.10.6
Git commit: 6247962
Built: Sun Feb 10 04:28:48 2019
OS/Arch: windows/amd64
Experimental: false

```
PS C:\data1> docker commit fcc9a5618b85 test:v1 #Committing Container

Error response from daemon: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: time=“2019-04-02T12:22:17+05:30” level=error msg=“hcsshim::ImportLayer failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3) path=\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\5bb9eea39e188d382fb8f336112584f3100797ac9fa887012e70c78fa7f2245a folder=C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\hcs981676719”
hcsshim::ImportLayer failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3) path=?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\5bb9eea39e188d382fb8f336112584f3100797ac9fa887012e70c78fa7f2245a folder=C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\hcs981676719
```

**Expected Results:**

```
PS C:\temp> docker commit suspicious_babbage temp-mysql:v1
sha256:6b4ddfffe4743cc21894ff3beb173fb7d24a7646f0c1b1fcb948eb60832717b1
```

**Actual Result:**

```
PS C:\data1> docker commit fcc9a5618b85 test:v1 #Committing Container

Error response from daemon: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: time=“2019-04-02T12:22:17+05:30” level=error msg=“hcsshim::ImportLayer failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3) path=\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\5bb9eea39e188d382fb8f336112584f3100797ac9fa887012e70c78fa7f2245a folder=C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\hcs981676719”
hcsshim::ImportLayer failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3) path=?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\5bb9eea39e188d382fb8f336112584f3100797ac9fa887012e70c78fa7f2245a folder=C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\hcs981676719
```